# Clock function in Stata 9

Tags: function, clock, stata

I am using an old version of Stata, Stata 9, and I am trying to use the `clock()` function to convert some dates.

`gen double Sgytime = clock (surgerystartdatetime, "dmyhm")`.

Stata says `clock not found`. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have an extra space between clock and the first parenthesis:

```
.  display %tc clock("5-12-1998 11:15", "MDY hm")
12may1998 11:15:00

.  display %tc clock ("5-12-1998 11:15", "MDY hm")
clock not found
```

I am assuming that in the search for lost time you have already verified that Stata (and not STATA) 9 has the clock function by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The function `clock()` was introduced in Stata 10. That is documented for all to see at http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?whatsnew9to10

Your options are to find a version of Stata that is 10 or higher, to write your own commands (not functions) to handle date-time data, or to use the user-written command `ntimeofday` published in the *Stata Journal*. `search ntimeofday` will indicate a download source. Note that the latter command does not work as `clock()` does, and in general Stata 9 just does not recognise date-time variables as such.

A larger question is that you are evidently getting ideas from material written for later versions of Stata, but the `help` and manuals for Stata 9 are the only completely reliable guide to what *functions* are available to you.